# Multiple Columns with Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql

Currently, I have a MySQL table that has a few columns in it. The following is a sample of the table with data:

```
+----------+---------------------+
| hospt_id | file_id | clinic_id |
+----------+---------------------+
|   212837 |       9 |      NULL |
|   123837 |      14 |   2134319 |
|   345567 |       9 |      NULL |
|   123456 |      14 |   2134320 |
|   123456 |      14 |   2134320 |
+----------+---------------------+`
```

What I am trying to do is to write a query that will return all records where the three columns are repeate.

For example, the last two rows are repeated. So I would want to get those returned. I know how to do duplicate searches for a single column, but not sure how to do for multiple columns.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to group by all three records to get a count of how many rows are in each group. You can then filter it down to those that have more than one matching row in the `having` clause.

```
select hospt_id, file_id, clinic_id, count(*)
  from <table>
  group by hospt_id, file_id, clinic_id
  having count(*) > 1;
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91bf9/2